shutdownOutput() is not supported in SSLSocket while using CloseableHttpClien close method
Oracle Java Version: 1.8.0_192
HttpClient JAR: 5.4
Upon using ClosableHttpClient with try with resource
try(ClosableHttpClient clinet = ......){
    //...
}

I am getting this error:

The method shutdownOutput() is not supported in SSLSocket when CLosableHttpClient close() method is called on completion of the try block

Is there any way to fix this?
I have tried:

Calling client.close() explicitly.
Without using try-with-resource and nornmal try-catch block when calling the close() method.
Upgrading HttpClient JAR to 5.4.1

